# Using a flow to log a user out of their session

Tags: visual-workflow, user, session, loginflow

Is there a declarative way to log a user out of their session using a flow, or is a Visualforce page the only way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had a similar question where someone wanted to use flow to force a logout: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_logout.htm

Here is the developers guide on a logout call: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_logout.htm

Users can be logged out of a session by using OOB security functionality found in Setup -> Session Settings